# Pairs of Integers Syntax

Tags: javascript

I am writing code for a pairs of interger problem.  I am not having issues with the logic, but rather when my contains function is called, it terminates my loop.

```
function contains(val,pairs){
    console.log(val + " " + pairs);
    for(i=0 ; i < pairs.length; i ++){
        if(pairs[i] === val){
            return true;
        }else if(pairs[i] > val){
            //since its sorted... we havent found it if > val
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function findSumPairs(intArr, sumTotal){
    pairs = [];
    sorted = intArr.sort();
    for(i = 0 ; i < sorted.length; i++){
        var c = (contains(sumTotal-sorted[i],sorted));
        console.log(i);
        //if(c === true){
        //    pairs.push(([i,sumTotal-sorted[i]]));
        //}
    }
    return pairs;
}

console.log(findSumPairs([-1, 0, 1, 2], 3));
```

my output right now is:

```
4 -1,0,1,2
4
[]
```

but if i remove the contains expression function call I get it to loop though the four integers correctly.  does the return of the helper function terminate the loop in any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable 'i' is a global variable in your codes.
add a keyword 'var' on front of 'i'. check next codes.

```
function contains(val,pairs) {
    console.log(val + " " + pairs);
    for (var i=0 ; i < pairs.length; i ++) {
        if (pairs[i] === val){
            return true;
        } else if (pairs[i] > val) {
            //since its sorted... we havent found it if > val
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function findSumPairs(intArr, sumTotal) {
    var pairs = [];
    var sorted = intArr.sort();
    for (var i = 0 ; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        var c = (contains(sumTotal-sorted[i],sorted));
        console.log(i);
        //if(c === true){
        //    pairs.push(([i,sumTotal-sorted[i]]));
        //}
    }
    return pairs;
}

console.log(findSumPairs([-1, 0, 1, 2], 3));
```

You can find info about javascript variables in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables).